# legend is not showing in in python cartopy

Tags: python, geometry, legend, shapefile, cartopy

I am trying to add shapefiles in cartopy feature in python. But it doesn't show the legend.
I have tried using....

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

# create a figure and set the projection
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# add the shapefiles with labels
ax.add_geometries(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m',
                                                edgecolor='black', facecolor='gray',
                                                label='Land').geometries(),
                  ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  facecolor='gray', edgecolor='black')
ax.add_geometries(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', '50m',
                                                edgecolor='face', facecolor='blue',
                                                label='Ocean').geometries(),
                  ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  facecolor='blue', edgecolor='face')

# add a title, gridlines and a colorbar
ax.set_title('Map with Shapefile Legend')
ax.gridlines()

# create the legend
ax.legend(loc='lower left')

plt.show()
```

The output returns an image where a box appeared in the lower left marked in a red circle with a error ...

```
No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument
```

[image]

Does anybody have any suggestions to show the legend properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a proxy artist, as described [here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/hurricane_katrina.html). Some types of handles [cannot be automatically associated to a legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) without that. Add this code:

```
land = mpatches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, facecolor="gray")
ocean = mpatches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, facecolor="blue")

labels = ['land', 'ocean']

plt.legend([land, ocean], labels,
               loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.025, -0.1), fancybox=True)
```